# How to get rid of scribbled lines in plotly line plot?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a subplot using plotly where I have some line plots and all the plots in the subplot needs to share the same x-axis as shown.

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=5, 
    cols=1, 
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    subplot_titles=['Count / Anzahl', 'min_nValue', 'max_nValue', 'avg_nValue', 'sum_nValue'],
    shared_xaxes=True,
)
fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df_dict_nValueAgg['Erste_15_Minuten']['KurzName'],
    y=df_dict_nValueAgg['Erste_15_Minuten']['min_nValueNorm'],
    name = "min_nValue_" + "Erste_15_Minuten",
    mode='lines+markers',
    #legendgroup = 2
), row=2, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df_dict_nValueAgg['Erste_15_Minuten']['KurzName'],
    y=df_dict_nValueAgg['Erste_15_Minuten']['max_nValueNorm'],
    name = "max_nValue_" + "Erste_15_Minuten",
    mode='lines+markers',
    #legendgroup = 2
), row=2, col=1)
.
.
.
# couple of plots more
.
.
fig.update_layout(
    legend_orientation="v", 
    height=1000, 
    width=2000,  
    title_text=currentEventTitle+pastEventTitle+nAttributes,
)
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45)
fig.write_image('fig1.png')
fig.show()
```

which gives me this figure

[image]
So I filter the data for each

The last three plots produces scribbled lines. Now I understand that since I am filtering the data based on four values of a column i.e. Erste_15_Minuten, Zweite_15_Minuten, Dritte_15_Minuten and Letzte_15_Minuten the number of xticks for the last three plots are unequal or maybe in different order. Is there a way where I can avoid this problem? Switching to Bar Plot would avoid this problem but I need to use only line plot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your sample code does not include any data or how the *scribble* plots are produced.  it appears that you x-axis is a categorical, I would think you need to "filter" by placing NaN in y-axis values and x-axis remains consistent across all sub-plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- from looking at your code.  There are multiple data frames of same format in a **dict**
- there is no guarantee that these dataframes are in same *KurzName* order
- have simulated data to match above understanding
- then have provided a way to re-order data frames to be consistent with third for generating line plots

  1. merge to first dataframe on *KurzName*
  2. use index of first dataframe to define sort order
- looking at image

  - bar chart - ok, not order dependent
  - first line chart is *scribbled*, second is not
  - hence forcing order of data frames has resolved the issue

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# fmt: off
words = ['adipisci', 'aliquam', 'amet', 'consectetur', 'dolor', 'dolore', 'dolorem', 'eius', 'est', 'etincidunt', 'ipsum', 'labore', 'magnam', 'modi', 'neque', 'non', 'numquam', 'porro', 'quaerat', 'quiquia', 'quisquam', 'sed', 'sit', 'tempora', 'ut', 'velit', 'voluptatem']
# fmt: on

r = np.random.choice(words, [2, 30])
r = np.char.add(r[0], np.char.add("_", r[1]))

# Erste_15_Minuten, Zweite_15_Minuten, Dritte_15_Minuten and Letzte_15_Minuten the number
df_dict_nValueAgg = {}
for k in [
    "Erste_15_Minuten",
    "Zweite_15_Minuten",
    "Dritte_15_Minuten",
    "Letzte_15_Minuten",
]:
    np.random.shuffle(r)
    df_dict_nValueAgg[k] = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "KurzName": r,
            "Count": np.random.randint(100, 300, len(r)),
            "min_nValueNorm": np.random.uniform(0, 0.5, len(r)),
            "max_nValueNorm": np.random.uniform(0.5, 1, len(r)),
        }
    )

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=5,
    cols=1,
    vertical_spacing=0.05,
    subplot_titles=[
        "Count / Anzahl",
        "min_nValue",
        "max_nValue",
        "avg_nValue",
        "sum_nValue",
    ],
    shared_xaxes=True,
)

for k in df_dict_nValueAgg.keys():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            x=df_dict_nValueAgg[k]["KurzName"], y=df_dict_nValueAgg[k]["Count"], name=k
        ),
        row=1,
        col=1,
    )


# this will be scibbled as each dataframe is in a different order
for k in df_dict_nValueAgg.keys():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df_dict_nValueAgg[k]["KurzName"],
            y=df_dict_nValueAgg[k]["max_nValueNorm"],
            name=k + " scribble max",
        ),
        row=4,
        col=1,
    )

# force order of dataframes to be same as first
for i, k in enumerate(df_dict_nValueAgg.keys()):
    df = df_dict_nValueAgg[k]
    if i > 0:
        df = df.merge(
            df_dict_nValueAgg[list(df_dict_nValueAgg.keys())[0]]
            .loc[:, "KurzName"]
            .reset_index(),
            on="KurzName",
        ).sort_values("index")

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df["KurzName"],
            y=df["max_nValueNorm"],
            name=k + " max",
        ),
        row=5,
        col=1,
    )


fig
```

[image]